# angular 8 with asp.net core problem in angular material datepicker

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular8

in angular i am using angular material datepicker 
when i select date from datepicker and submit the form 
the server side (asp.net core ) receiving the date minus one day
i make congole.log to see the value of selected date in client side . i found it correct but the problem in server side .
i am using this code in angular form angular material

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    monthYearLabel: 'YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'YYYY',

  },
};

 providers: [
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to debug the server side code then.

Comment: i confirmed about server side . the action receive object inside this object contain the received date . when i debug the server side and see the received date. i found it date - one date

Comment: any one helps me

Comment: What console.log code did you use? Use the F12 network monitor to inspect the JSON that is sent. Are the web server and dB server in the same time zone?

Comment: i use the f12 network monitor to inspect the json that is send. as you said to me when i select 2020-03-21 date in json data give me the vale  dt: "2020-03-20T21:00:00.000Z"

Comment: please help me Nick.McDermaid

Comment: this is value in server side {03/20/2020 09:00:00 م}

Comment: It’s some kind of time zone issue. Let me google

Comment: The value in The JSON message is UTC. The value you see server side is probably local time. Not sure how to fix it at this point.

Comment: The value in The JSON message is UTC is (selected date minus one day not the exact value that i select it ) . so the problem in client side (angular) if you find the solution please help me . thanks so much

Comment: i change angular material datepicker to  <input type="date" id="dt" name="dt" #dt="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="purchaseService.purchase.dt"> will give me the correct selected date in server side . so the problem in angular material datetimepicker . how solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

i sovled the problem finally by adding this code in angular Modules.ts

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    monthYearLabel: 'YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'YYYY',

  },
};
}

  providers: [ 
    {provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: {useUtc: true}},

    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]
    },

    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
```